# Laravel chained/linked select box failed to load resource status 500 internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select, laravel

#### Complete Edit

I've edited my original question as I've refined my code which has put me in a much better position to define a better error

Hi I'm creating a chained select box that will once a client is selected find the clients projects.

The ajax is doing its job it knows which client has been selected and my console tells me the following:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://itempus.dev/task/clientsprojects?option=5`

The above option value refers to the client id which I want to pass into the projects db and find the clients projects. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate some help in a somewhat complex task for a newbie.

#### TaskController

```
public function create()
    {
        $tasks = Auth::user()->tasks;   
        $client_options = DB::table('clients')->orderBy('client_name', 'asc')->lists('client_name','id');
        $team_options = DB::table('teams')->orderBy('team_member_name', 'asc')->lists('team_member_name','id', 'team_member_category');
        return View::make('tasks.create', array('project_options' => $project_options, 'team_options' => $team_options, 'client_options' => $client_options));
}       
        
public function clientsprojects() {
        
        $input = Input::get('option');
        $client_id = Project::find($input);
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->where('client_id', $client_id->id)
                                           ->orderBy('project_name')
                                           ->lists('id','project_name');
        $models = $project->projects();
        return Response::eloquent($models->get(array('id','project_name')));    
        }
```

#### views/tasks/create.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'TaskController@store', 'id' => 'createuser')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        @if(count($client_options)>0)
 
           {{ Form::label('select_client', 'Assign to Client', array('class' => 'awesome client_option'));  }}
        {{ Form::select('client', $client_options , Input::old('client'), array('class' => 'tempus_select client_option', 'id' => 'select_client')) }}

        @endif 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group deletegates">
 
            {{ Form::label('select_client', 'Assign to Project', array('class' => 'awesome'));  }}
        {{ Form::select('project', array_merge(array('default' => 'Please Select')), 'default', array('class' => 'tempus_select', 'id' => 'project_select')) }}

     </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Create the task!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#select_client').change(function(){
        $.get("{{ url('task/clientsprojects')}}", 
        { option: $(this).val() }, 
        function(data) {
            var model = $('#project_select');
            model.empty();

            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                model.append("<option value='"+ element.id +"'>" + element.name + "</option>");
            });
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Route.php

I've also defined my route as so:

```
Route::get('task/clientsprojects', function(){
    $input = Input::get('option');
    $client_id = Project::find($input);
    $projects = DB::table('projects')->where('client_id', $client_id->id)
                               ->orderBy('project_name')
                               ->lists('id','project_name');
    $models = $project->projects();
    return Response::eloquent($models->get(array('id','project_name')));
});
```

Comment: i am tending to give it a -1 for lack of research.... using your own keyowrds __chained select box__, i found [**this**](http://www.blueicestudios.com/chained-select-boxes-using-php-mysql-ajax/)

Comment: @itachi yes but i have no idea how to make this work with laravel, perhaps you'd be as kind as to help?

Comment: laravel is just the framework. use it as the old php. laravel doesn't have some magic methods to make it work. just use get variables in the ajax request, send the data in response and then unhide the next select with repopulating the value. give it a try. you need to be specific about where you are stuck at. as of now, question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the **create** function in the **TaskController** works correctly and creates the first drop down menu for the clients.

When this drop down changes value, an ajax get request is sent to the server but you receive a **500 (Internal Server Error)** because something is wrong with your queries.

So lets try to fix that.

```
Route::get('task/clientsprojects', function(){

    // Get the option value which is the client_id

    $client_id = Input::get('option'); 

    // Get all projects that have client_id = $client_id 

    $projects = DB::table('projects')

    ->where('client_id', $client_id)

    ->orderBy('project_name')

    ->lists('id','project_name');

    //Return the response to the client

    return Response::json($projects);
});
```

Now the response is back to the client. Replace your JavaScript with the following.

```
$(document).ready(function($){

  $('#select_client').change(function(){

    $.get("{{ url('task/clientsprojects')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 

      function(data) {

        var projects = $('#project_select');

        projects.empty();

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {   

          projects

          .append($("<option></option>")

          .attr("value",key)

          .text(value)); 
        });

      });

  });

});
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: thanks for that, its been solved, but I tested yours and it worked too, so i'll award you the bounty.

Comment: you reckon you could help solve this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408612/laravel-eloquent-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object

Comment: Very kind of you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need some `JavaScript (AJAX)` to accomplish this, basically, a select element has a `change` event which fires upon changing any value, I mean, if user selects an item then the `change` event fires and you have to declare a `change` event handler in `JavaScript` for you `client` `combo/select` element. There are so many ways to use an event handler, for example (Your select should contain an id as `id='select_client'`):

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('select_client').onchange = function(){
        // ...
    };
};
```

Or you may use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener) and if you use a library like `jQuery` then you may do it using something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#select_client" ).change(function(e) { // i.e. '/get_progects/{clientId}'
        e.preventDefault();
        var clients = $(this);
        $.getJson('yuordomain/get_projects/' + clients.val(), function(response){
            // id = 'projects' for projects combo.select
            var projects = $('#projects');
                projects.empty();
                $.each('response.projects', function(k, v){
                    var option = $('<option/>', {'id':v.id, 'text':v.projectName});
                    projects.append(option);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

This will simply, fetch the data (projects depending on the selected client) from server when ever a user selects the `client` dropdown box and to make this work you need to declare a route for fetching the projects dasta, for example:

```
Route::get('/get_progects', function($client_id){
    // I'm using a closure here but you should use a class method
    $projects = Project::where('client_id', $client_id)
                       ->orderBy('project_name')
                       ->lists('id','project_name');
    return Response::json(compact('projects'));
});
```

This is the very basic idea and hope you can implement it in your project now.

Comment: thanks for your help, i've updated my question with some errors, would you be able to help?